# Force close when I run app

Tags: java, android, android-logcat, forceclose

I was trying build app to calculate area of plane figure and when I test this app, this app getting force close when start.

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout persegi, pp, bk, s;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        persegi = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.click_persegi);
        pp = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.click_persegi_panjang);
        bk = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.click_belah_ketupat);
        s = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.click_segitiga);           

        persegi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LuasPersegi.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        pp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LuasPersegiPanjang.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        bk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LuasBelahKetupat.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LuasSegitiga.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/primary_material_dark"
    tools:context="com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pilihan :"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/click_persegi">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/persegi"
                android:id="@+id/gambar_persegi"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/persegi"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/click_persegi_panjang">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/persegi_panjang"
                android:id="@+id/gambar_persegi_panjang"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/persegi_panjang"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/click_segitiga">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/segitiga"
                android:id="@+id/gambar_segitiga"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/segitiga"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/click_belah_ketupat">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/belah_ketupat"
                android:id="@+id/gambar_belah_ketupat"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/belah_ketupat"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="#80000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and I don't know what happened, but the logcat always shown like this

```
> .luasbangundatar/com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2450)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5465)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
  at com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5465) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #178: Error inflating class <unknown>
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
  at com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5465) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
  at com.amalhanaja.luasbangundatar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2510) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5465) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11366924 byte allocation with 2146744 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2728)
  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2633)
  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(I
```

Comment: Failed to allocate a 11366924 byte allocation with 2146744 free. You're trying to use large images in your views.

Comment: Thanks, it really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inflate exception is not actually the problem, but really comes from another deeper issue in your layout that is then wrapped in an InflateException. A common issue is an out of memory exception when trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

Answer (score 0):

Please define Theme in your manifest activity tag as AppCompat, Like below 
 `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"`

It may be solve crash, because you are extended AppCompatActivity but i think you are not set theme as AppCompat

Try it.